# How to write this in idiomatic awk?

Tags: awk, idioms

The following program prints out the name of the file, the number of rows, and the number of rows that begin with `//` in the case that more than one fifth of the rows begin that way.

```
awk '$1 == "//" { a+=1 } END { if (a * 5 >= NR) {print FILENAME " " NR " " a}}' MyClass.java
```

This works, but the nested `{{}}` make me question if I'm doing it right, knowing that the typical structure of an awk program is:

```
awk 'condition { actions }'
```

So I suspect that something like

```
awk '$1 == "//" { a+=1 } END  && (a * 5 >= NR) {print FILENAME " " NR " " a}' MyClass.java
```

would be more appropriate, but every such attempt gives syntax errors. Is there a right way to do this, or is my approach as good as it gets.

Comment: It works and it's readable. What more could you want?

Comment: I guess the 'what more' that I could want is that it would be written in the way one experienced with awk would expect. Perhaps it is, I don't know.

Comment: I don't see why nested blocks would be unidiomatic -- quite the contrary. If the inner block disturbs you, it is optional as long as the block contains a single statement, but it's actually good form to keep the block delimiters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are other ways to express it, but you wrote it idiomatically the first time. Although the authors tend to omit braces whenever they can, you can still find examples of code like that throughout *The AWK Programming Language*. They should know.

It seems like Aho, Weinberger, and Kernighan have several centuries of development experience in languages whose syntax derives from C. And when they write something like this

```
if (a * 5 >= NR) 
    print FILENAME " " NR " " a
```

it communicates perfectly that the block following the `if` statement is supposed to contain one and only one statement.

I have considerably fewer centuries of experience. Whenever I *read* something like that, it communicates perfectly that a) somebody forgot to type {}, and b) somebody else is about to introduce a bug by adding a statement to that block without adding the braces.

Over the years, I've trained myself to type this whenever I type an `if`.

```
if () {}
```

Then I go back and fill it in, breaking lines if I need to.  In my normal editor, "if" expands automatically to "if () {}". I'm pretty sure I haven't omitted braces even once since the mid-1980s.